# Unable to load table from "Select data from source" in Qlik sense

Tags: qliksense

I use Data manager to update my **Qlik** app, due to some reason I am unable to load table through **Select data from source** feature.

I can preview my table and edit or modify data in Data manager but unable to upload via   **Select data from source** feature.

[See image for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HveLl.png)

Comment: Does the file path in Qlik match the file path of the actual file? E.g., did you move it?